# Git exclude folder from pushing to repository

Tags: git, github

My repository consists of two folders `client` and `server`. In `server` I have few folders which were automatically generated by `Codeblocks` IDE like `bin` and `obj`. I dont want to store them in my repository, so I decided to add `.gitignore`. I tried everything:

```
# folders
**/bin/
**bin/
**/bin
**bin
bin
/bin
bin/
/bin/
server/bin
/server/bin
server/bin/
server/bin
```

And still after `pull` and making `git status` I can see that `bin` folder will be pushed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do the files appear in `git status`?

Comment: `new file: server/bin/Debug/chat server`
`new file: server/obj/Debug/chat.o`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: Even if I use `git rm -r --cached .` and `git add .` the `bin` folder is still being tracked.

Comment: @destroyer - Only a dup (of that quesiton) if the person asking realizes that the file was already tracked and that they're wanting git to "forget" the file.  "Same answer" is not the same thing as "dup".

Comment: @DavidKonn - Why are you running `git add .` after the `git rm --cached` command?  The `add` will undo the `rm`.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger so I cant use `git add .`? I thought I can and `.gitignore` would take care of untracked files.

Comment: @DavidKonn - Perhaps I misunderstood the procedure you're using; which is why I asked the question of why you ran the procedure you did.  If you have ignore rules in place, then you can use `git add .`; it's not clear to me why you'd do that while trying to clean up your index.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger "I can see that bin folder will be pushed" implies the files were added to the index, which means this _is_ a duplicate.

Comment: @destoryer - Nope.  "Same situation" or "same solution" does not make the QUESTION a dup.  If the knowledge gap on the part of the person asking is different, it's not a dup.  You and plenty of people around here would rather mark everything dup than actually answer questions, but that doesn't make it so.

Comment: Yeah, and same question makes it a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

In comments, you show that each file is listed as a "new file".  You don't specify whether these show as "changes to be committed" or "untracked files"; but in the case of untracked files, if no files in a directory are tracked then only the directory (not the individual files) would be listed by default.

So it seems the problem is that files in these directories are in the index, which means git can't ignore them.  You could remove them from the index

```
git rm -r --cached server/bin
git rm -r --cached server/obj
```

Comment: It says `fatal: pathspec 'server/bin' did not match any files`. What I noticed is when i change branch to `master` it is not tracking `bin` folder. After changing to my second branch it is tracking that folder.

Comment: Now, in `.gitignore` I have `*.o`. I added new file `t.o` and when I use `git status` I can see, that this file is set as `untracked`. I think it should ignore this file. Ehh...